# VSCode show element index in array

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I hava big arrays inside vscode and most count elements to find index of one element inside an array !
I need something inside VSCode to show me array index to make my work easy.

```
function: [
    {
      type: "word",
    },
    {
      type: "operator",
      data: ":",
    },
    {
      type: "word",
      most:types,
      check: 12,
    },
    {
      type: "word",
      require: true,
    },
    {
      type: "operator",
      data: ",",
      check: 0,
    },
    {
      type: "word",
      require: true,
    },
    {
      type: "word",
      require: true,
      loop:12
    },
  ]
```

Comment: there should be some extension, but keep your array at 0 line and your first element should be at line 1 - lol the Q itself is crazy tbh

Comment: i cant make my array elements in one line ! my elements is objects and with diferent properties

Comment: I didn;t mean a single line, but the same way you have shown above .... anyway the Q is odd for me atleast

Comment: you are better of with a `Map` if you need to search a lot in a list

Comment: JSON is whitespace independent, you can remove all spaces (not in strings) and newlines and the file has the same information

Comment: `ctrl + shift + p` then type `> Format Document` and the line numbers will tell you enough. You may only need some minor simple math to realize what index each of the items in the array is.

Answer (score 2):

clang has a freature called "inlay hints" which does exactly what you need. You may check if jlang supports the same feature as well.